# How to edit element.style in my wordpress site?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a woocommerce WordPress site and I have the following code in html (from a product on my site)

```
<img role="presentation" alt="" src="https://thatsshejeans.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/53A9274-1.jpg" class="zoomImg" style="position: absolute; top: -444.334px; left: -144.9px; opacity: 0; width: 1087px; height: 1630px; border: none; max-width: none; max-height: none;">
```

I would like to edit this code using CSS, specifically the max-width part. I managed to make a modification in the position:absolute  as follows:

```
div [style^="position: absolute"]{
 position:fixed !important;}
```

but when trying to do the same thing for the max-width it just doesn't work... I tried:

```
div [style^="max-width: none"]{
 max-width:1200px !important;}
```

but it did not work. If anyone can help me I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- When using `style^=` the text you're searching for must be at the start of the string. I used `style*=` instead.
- When changing the `max-width`, you also need to adjust the `width`.
- I have removed part of the styles (for instance `opacity: 0`) to make it visible.

For more information on attribute selectors, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```css
img[style*="max-width"] {
  max-width: 100px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<img role="presentation" alt="" src="https://thatsshejeans.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/53A9274-1.jpg" class="zoomImg" style="position: absolute; width: 1087px; height: 1630px; border: none; max-width: none; max-height: none;">
```